# How can i apply the Shopping Cart Pricing Rule?

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

Row total in cart,

```
Below $25 get 25% discount 
below $50 get 30% discount 
Below $75 get 35% discount 
Above $75 get 40% discount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one  can be implement by below conditions :

[image]

[image]

in the same way, you can create other 3 shopping cart price rules.....

Give **highest priorty** for **smaller discount**s.

```
Priority 1 for less than 25 

Priority 2 for  25 - 50

Priority 3 for  50 - 75

Priority 4 for  above 75
```

[image]

Comment: What about my other conditions.

Comment: @zus create 4 shopping cart price rules for 4 conditions.... all you need to do is changing the conditions , thats all....

Comment: This is mine, https://snag.gy/icXwZb.jpg All condition set by individually.

Comment: After setting the condition, if my total $35, my condition not working. As per my condition Discount amount is $30, but applied $25, may i know the reason?

Comment: Did you understand my error?

Comment: @zus try with the configuration that i posted in answer.....

Comment: Okay, but may i know the diff b/w row total and subtotal?

Comment: You need to set priorities too so that they get checked for conditions in the right order otherwise, for example,  a sale for $10 could get one of three rules applied

Comment: @zus `row total` = item row total + item tax amount + item hidden tax amount + item row wee amount after discount - item discount amount

Comment: @jscar could you pls explain related to mine?

Comment: the priority of a rule determines the order in which they are applied. In order to apply the right one and stop further rules processing you need to assign the priorities so they are applied in the correct order.

Comment: @BabyinMagento Nope, not working. Price $36, expected discount 30%, but applied discount 35%.

Comment: @zus as Jscar mentioned, you need to give 1st priority for `Below $25 get 25% discount ` & so on..... give highest priority for smaller discounts.....

Comment: @zus i updated answer, follow the same....